# Looking for a way to list the size of all tables in BigQuery Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I am working with a bunch of tables in GCP, and I'm hoping to find a way to list the size of all the tables (there are a lot).  I tried this.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du

That shows the size one one object, which is fine for a very small number of tables.  I was hoping to find a way to loop through all objects, and I'm dealing with a lot of tables here.  I'd love to find a solution where I can get Python to do the job, but if it's just a pure SQL solution, that's fine too.  Something that grabs metadata from the `'information_schema.tables'` would be great.  Please share some sample code, if you have been through this exercise already.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok, I see how it works.  You generate a .json file from BQ, save it locally, and reference it like this:
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('C:/your_path_here.123456789.json')

Answer (score 0):

This query can pull metadata for actual tables.
If I remember correctly, I don't think this will work for views though, physical tables only.  This also limits you to querying one dataset at a time.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  project_id,
  dataset_id,
  table_id,
  DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(SAFE_CAST(CEIL(creation_time/60/60/24/1000) AS INT64)) created_date,
  DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(SAFE_CAST(CEIL(last_modified_time/60/60/24/1000) AS INT64)) modified_date,
  TRUNC(row_count/1000000,2) row_count_in_millions,
  TRUNC(size_bytes/1073741824,2) size_gb,
  type
FROM dataset.__TABLES__
```

Comment: This will only work with one dataset unfortunately. What if you want to list all tables in all datasets? ;-)

Comment: That is a problem that I mentioned in the answer.
I don't know of a way to query all datasets purely in the browser SQL console, but you can use the **google-big-query** python package to write a for loop.